# How do troubleshoot E1614 for PowerEdge 2950

Tags: windows-server-2012, dell-poweredge

My PowerEdge 2950 starts and runs for a about 1-2 hours and shots down, with error E1614 PS, E1624 and E1610. No matter which PS unit i use. How do i begin to troubleshoot this?

I understand that those codes tell me that there is no power, but it does work for 1 or 2 hours.

Also, it will only shot down if i login to windows server, if i just go into the bios and keep it running it will not shut down.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have reinserted both Power Supplies, both of their power LED's are green. Both PS are plugged into different AC power lines. Both have their fans working. Is it not strange that only when i load windows server does it shut off after two hours?

Comment: Not really. I would expect one or both of them to possibly be a bit unreliable after running nonstop for 12 years.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 3):

You start by looking up the error codes in the [Dell PowerEdge 2950 Hardware Owner's Manual](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-2950_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf).

When you do this, you will find the explanation of all three error codes, and instructions for resolving the problem.

You will find that all three errors indicate a loss of PSU redundancy due to a power supply failing to supply any power. Further, you will be referred to the section "Troubleshooting Power Supplies" on page 118.

When you actually go to that section you will see a short checklist which can be boiled down to: remove and reinstall the PSU, and if that doesn't work, replace the PSU. (You must also supply it with AC power, of course, but if you aren't experienced with servers it may not be obvious that you have to plug in both of them.)

But you still should check the manual for yourself, to learn what you can from it, and to see about any details that might have been omitted here in this brief guide to how to begin to troubleshoot the problem.

---

Before you get too far into buying a new PSU, though, you should consider that this whole ancient system is unlikely to be worth the cost of a replacement PSU, pull any potentially useful components out of it, and send the server back to the recycling stream.